# How to validate users with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am working on a simple login and signup page to learn ASP.NET MVC log in pages, and currently I have a signup page that works and saves the users details when signing up into a database under a new collection (each user registered has their own collection in the database), and so then when they try to login on the login page, if the password inputted in the form matches the password on the database, they get redirected to a view that I have called "LoggedIn".
The code on my controller for the sign in button that occurs once a user presses sign in as follows:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignInButton(IFormCollection form)
        {
            //null checker
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form["email"].ToString()) || 
                    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form["password"].ToString()))
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Please fill both fields";
                return View("Login");
            }
            string email = form["email"].ToString();
            string inputpassword = form["password"].ToString();
            //checking if email exists in the system
            if (DoesCollectionExist(email) != true)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Email does not exist.";
                return View("Login");
            }

            var collection = database.GetCollection<User>(email);
            //how to target password
            var documents = await collection.FindAsync(_ => true);
            var password = String.Empty;
            var firstname = String.Empty;
            foreach (var document in documents.ToList())
            {
                password = $"{document.Password}";
                firstname = $"{document.FirstName}";
            }
            //password checker
            if (password == inputpassword)
            {
                //this is where I will add validation once I figure out how to do so. 
                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }
            
            //else return Login and give message password incorrect
            ViewData["Message"] = "Password is incorrect";
            return View("Login");
        }
```

I would like to create almost like a viewdata variable which states the user is authenticated, one that is stored in the session or cookie data, so that when a user trys to go to the LoggedIn page, unless they have acquire the viewdata-like variable stating they are authenticated, they will not be able to view the page/view. I would also like to parse their firstname, so that on the LoggedIn page it says Hello "their name".

How can I do this? How can I validate users using a simple method.

Comment: If this is for playing around / testing / etc, fine, but I would use the ASP.NET Identity libraries to implement authentication / authorization / roles / etc. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: Use `Session["Name"] = firstname` above `return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");` line. And on LoggedIn page view use `<p>Hello @Session["Name"]</p>`

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb When I try writing Session["Name"] it says 'the name 'session' does not exist in the current context. Just so you know, the SignInButton code I wrote above is in a HomeController class inherited from Controller.

Comment: @mv1999 Add `System.Web.Mvc` namespace above this controller